# how to read html tag's content by BeautifuSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<td class="tag">
    <a href="/tag/android"  rel="tag">
         <img src="http://127.0.0.1/idf2.png" >
    android
    </a>          
</td>
```

the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print html.td.a.string   # output None
```

which metthod in BeautifulSoup4 can retrive `<a>`'s content `android`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `.text`, not `.string`:

```
>>>> soup.td.a.text.strip()
u'android'
```

Note that I've `strip`ped it because otherwise it would also contain newlines.

Also you should probably sonider some other way of finding the exact `a` tag you need to extract text from, as there might be many `a` tags on the page and this way you'll get only the first one. But that depends, of course, on your criterion which you use to find the right tag.